# Can I drive nitinol wire with an LED driver?

Tags: power-supply, constant-current

I am using [0.010" nitinol shape memory alloy wire](http://www.robotshop.com/en/dynalloy-flexinol-010-lt-actuator-wire.html) ([Datasheet](http://www.dynalloy.com/pdfs/TCF1140.pdf)) to actuate a lock.  The wire needs to be resistively heated to actuate, and I have empirically measured the cool resistance to be 0.83 Ω (~3").

When using a lab power supply with a constant current limit of 700 mA, the system works wonderfully, but for production we are looking to use a single 12VDC 2A supply for the system.  As this supply is expected to heat the wire and while still powering the control circuitry I need something to limit current.  The device does not have forced cooling or room for large heatsinks, so we do need to stay fairly efficient.

How can I embed a simple ~700 mA supply?  Would a buck converter intended for driving LEDs work?  ([1](http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX5035.pdf), [2](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva265/slva265.pdf), [3](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/AL8805.pdf))

These are niche devices – if it is not possible to do this efficiently with a low part count, a <$30 prebuilt module is within budget.

Comment: You could use a buck convertor, but it's probably overkill. A simple 1:20 PWM driver is probably all you need.

Comment: @Trevor, I understand how I can control the heating of the wire by modulating the full 2A supply, but how can I do that without knocking out my control circuitry?  I only have one supply.

Comment: You would need to add an inductor in the line so the current averages at 700ma. (plus a flyback diode of course)

Comment: You can make is smarter by adding a sense resistor of course.

Comment: or there is always this thing http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/80421fb.pdf

Comment: or a http://www.ti.com/product/LM3405

Comment: So your spec is 12V,2A (24W) capacity input  and 700mA CC out into 0.83Ω cold or <0.6W out ? that's all ?   What is R at 70'C? How you sense T?

Comment: Well @TonyStewart.EEsince'75, when you put it that way, the 2A supply sounds a bit silly :).  I do not have a measurement at 70C, but I know that my bench supply drops to ~2V (→ ~3 Ω).  Feedback is via a set of hall-effect sensors that measure the length of the wire (which is proportional to temperature).

Comment: Without detailed specs, I don't think you are ready to design something yet.  Just add a CC regulator ( 12V to xV constant current reg) >80% efficient to your shopping list. Losses depend on ESR of choke, MOSFET and output cap. & temp rise depends on thermal resistance ['C/W]

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75, I am happy to use a prebuilt assembly, but all of the CC regulators I can find are labeled as "LED drivers", hence the question "can I use an LED driver for nitinol?"

Comment: As long as said LED driver have a conpliance voltage range within the cold-to-hot-range of your heating wire to make it work, I would go for LED driver. EMC comes to mind immediately for all bought LED drivers on the market.

Comment: @Mitch,  LED drivers made for your input and an output of 1 or few equiv LED voltage should work down to 0.5V or limited by noise or <x % or rating .   Again it depends on specs. In general a Buck current regulator has a lower limit that depends on ; current sense R, voltage drop ( 50~100mV typ) , V amplifier to match ( like 1.25V) so Adj.current is  regulated by all these variables and controlled either ext. voltage or a pot . You also need an output enable.  EMI and layout are critical factors.

Comment: Special CC regulators have a wide dynamic range or ultra low ESR (<5m Ω to get high efficiency , but since your output < 1W , your 12V supply will have significantly more losses. but 700mA even with a short circuit load should be simple to make using above parts Buck Reg( 50mV current sense R , amp to To Vref compare for Feedback reg input. (FB) with controlled bandwidth for stability.

Comment: So load changes from 0.83 Ω  to 3 Ω or what?

Comment: You don't need constant current. Constant voltage will work fine because it is a resistive load. Use a buck capable of outputing a low voltage such as 0.8V. I have seen a few. You may put a small resistor in series with the output of the buck to further limit current and keep everything stable.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest LED CC drivers would be unsuitable for your application since your voltage requirement is so low.
You could use a simple PWM solution but this is completely unacceptable due to the high pulse current. (0.83 Ohms will result in 14 Amp pulses, which exceeds your wire current capability (may act like a fuse) so you need to have a switching solution with a step down inductor which increases complexity)

Looking at the Nitinol datasheet, you should have a maximum operating current of 1 Amp for your wire.
With your off resistance of 0.83 Ohms that requires a voltage of about 830 mV.

**Note:** The datasheet says your wire is 0.47 Ohms per inch ...so I'm not sure your question has the right values. Why is the resistance not 1.42 Ohms??

[image]

You could design a bespoke constant current switching regulator for the purpose, but I'd suggest a quite reasonable solution would be to use a TI [LM2596](http://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/LM2596-D.PDF) based Buck regulator which supplies a minimum voltage output of 1.235 V. 
You could simply use a 0.5 Ohm (1 W) series resistor so you pass 1 Amp when the Nitinol wire is cold. It's resistance goes down as it heats up so you can adjust the series resistor to ensure you don't overcurrent the wire when hot.

There are many LM2596 based Buck regulators on Ebay (I use them all the time as replacements for LM78XX regulators) at very cheap prices (around $1.50). There are also plenty of constant voltage/current modules, but they are really based on a foldback current design which I doubt you actually need.
You could design you own of course ...but I'd suggest the constant voltage modules would be fine for the task.

Be aware that no matter what approach you take, there will be pulse currents of at least 1 Amp drawn from your power supply. You may need to ensure you have sufficiently large output capacitors on your 12 V supply since it is limited to 2A.

Comment: Hysteric Continuous Conduction Mode (CCM) Buck regulators ought to have triangular currents over DC but well under rated (sat) current of choke.  Ripple voltage is irrelevant here as you very well pointed out.  Cap, FET & L [mΩ]  affects efficiency losses but reducing hysteresis range of CCM reduces peak/avg current  with some limitations. It should work down to 0V out since the 50~100mV Vense is what controls FB with ampilifer to internal Vref.

Comment: Agreed @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 and if the OP want to design his own solution using CCM: http://www.mouser.com/pdfdocs/BuckConverterDesignNote.pdf  It adds complexity of course, with a multiphase solution having the least ripple current.

Comment: for PWM RMS current is only 700mA, that's not going to need a fat wire.

Comment: Yes, this is good. There are even buck regulators with minimum output voltage as low as 0.8V.

Comment: Yes PWM with LC filter aka Buck regulator is  the way to go with suitable feedback for temp Resistance or current along with Hall sense for contraction sensing.  I would expect R to rise sharply with Temp as a better feedback to T and thus force but Op has not tested/reported this.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 ....Nitinol wire Resistance goes down as it heats up.

Comment: ok thanks.  I wish @Mitch could be more precise.   " I do not have a measurement at 70C, but I know that my bench supply drops to ~2V (→ ~3 Ω)

Answer (score -2):

For small loads PWM is  best

PWM is best. resistors don't respond to average voltage or current, they respond to average power. so the greatest heating efficiency if got by PWMing the load.

PWM will cause ripple on the supply, but the higher the frequency the smaller the ripple amplitude

so about 400mW into the load (when cold) from 12V requires a PWM ratio of about 300:1  the peak current will be about 15A but the RMS current only 700mA  ripple current in the filter caps slightly less than that figure.

driving the mosfet fast enough and limiting EMI are going to be the worst challenges,

Comment: I think you mean PWM with an inductor for stored energy is actually more efficient than non-inductive PWM because the peak current is lower

Comment: it's a trade-off between heating the mosfet (my plan) and heating the inductor and the diode, or second mosfet (your plan)    The load is a resistor so a high current at a low duty cycle is no less efficient than a low current at 100% duty cycle.

Comment: try again , PWM 12V/0.7A = 17.1Ω  , load starts at 0.83Ω, so passive R ratio= 0.83/17.1= 5% which means ripple current in supply cap can be up to 12V/0.8Ω= 15A peak stressing ESR in source cap ( overheat) . I agree your efficiency is same as a linear CC (100% duty cycle) and only 5% efficient due to R ratio, thats why SMPS or Class E Audio uses chokes to store energy.  So load of I²R= 0.7A * 0.83 (cold) = 0.5W and loss is 10 W

Comment: as far as heating from the ripple current is concerned it comes out about 3.2A RMS, so yeah. that could stress the filter caps a bit.

Comment: heat in caps and MOSFET, very low efficiency, more EMI and more issues with 15A pulses unless controlled, which is why LC filter is preferred to reduce Peak/avg current near 1.1

Comment: caps yeah, 10uF ceramic caps have about 0.1 ohm ESR so to survive the 3A RMS ripple current it might take 3 or so in parallel,  EMI  that's what ISM bands are for.  MOSFET drive could be an issue.

Comment: Then for 15A cold pulses with 10mOhm RdsOn is more than 2 watts so you need excessively large MOSFET.. so again for this PWM passive control is a poor solution using 12V into 0.8 Ohms that only needs 0.5W load   and EMI spews everything in AM and SW band (-1) IMO

Comment: current through the load is 700mA RMS, that same RMS current flows through R_ds(on) and a smaller current through the capacitors.

Comment: NO Passive PWM pulses about  12V/0.83Ohm =~14.5A at 0.7A/14A duty cycle

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56777/discussion-between-jasen-and-tony-stewart-ee-since-75).

Comment: @Jasen. Pulse current of 15 A can not be supported by the 12 V 2A power supply ...to do this you need very very large output capacitance.

Comment: yeah, but a capacitor will have no problem, the average current needed is less than 100mA (RMS is 700mA, average is much  less)

Comment: @Jasen, it may be feasible with a large capacitor, but will produce a large dV/dT, even so. Hard to believe it will be a good idea. Adding an inductor just seems like a good idea. OP did mention a desire to keep the circuitry small and minimize heat. So the buck topology seems to be called for.

Comment: 700mA is the RMS current, so that's all that will be responsible for any resistive loasses. The problem with buck is finding one that doesn't waste 100% extra energy in a sense resistor. else you run it open-loop and have to stay in discontinuous mode or else risk wind-up either way diode losses are going to be 50% of the output power...

Comment: @Mitch I'm looking to do something similar. How did the led drive work for you?